# Contraseñas con htpasswd

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

Tengo algunas dudas con este archivo `htpasswd`:

1. ¿Debo crear una carpeta para este archivo?
2. Si tengo 2 archivos `htaccess` en diferentes directorios, ¿necesito crear 2 `htpasswd` o 1 `htpasswd` sirve para los 2?
3. Para que los cambios se realicen, ¿debo reiniciar Apache? ¿Cuál sería la forma más sencilla de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. ¿debo crear una carpeta para este archivo ?

No, puedes colocar el archivo en cualquier carpeta existente. Lo recomendable por seguridad es que coloques el fichero en una carpeta por encima (fuera) del directorio root (el / accesible desde la web).

> 2. ¿si tengo 2 archivos htaccess en diferentes directorios -Necesito crear 2 htpasswd o 1 htpasswd sirve para los dos ?

Un único `htpasswd` valdría para los dos. Lo único es que puede que tengas que definir path's diferentes en cada fichero `htaccess`. Pero los dos podrán usarlo sin problemas (ejemplo: podría darse el caso de que tengas diferentes áreas protegidas dentro de tu sitio web pero los usuarios/contraseñas sean comunes en ambas).

> 3. ¿para que los cambios se realicen debo reiniciar apache? cual seria la forma mas sencilla de hacerlo?

Puede que me equivoque, pero después de realizar cambios en `htaccess` o `htpasswd` no necesitas reiniciar Apache. Aunque si los necesitases, podrías hacerlo desde la línea de comandos ejecutando esto:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Si usas alguna herramienta como WampServer, podrías hacer click con el botón secundario y seleccionar "Reiniciar todos los servicios" ("Restart all services").

Comment: Los votos negativos se justifican, por favor. Gracias.